# Have difficulty removing a program named "uninstallre.exe"

Tags: windows-10

This is the path of the program I wanna remove

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\uninstallre.exe
```

Everytime I wanna remove it, it pops up that I should be granted permission from -**desktop-vbi1m48\mike** to make changes to this file. When I type in "whoami" in the cmd,  **desktop-vbi1m48\mike** came out. So I assume it's not the problem of permission but something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove it via CMD

del /f "C:\Program Files (x86)\uninstallre.exe"

If it doesnt work, boot into safe mode and delete it from there.

Comment: It actually worked. Thank u. Bro. No need for safe mode

Comment: What does  cmd line mean?  Could u possibly explain that one?